# Как оптимизировать sql запрос (выборка из 1.5M строк)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация

Выбираю данные между двумя датами с количеством строк более миллиона таким запросом:

```
SELECT
  time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'MSK' AS time,
  type,
  CASE
    WHEN (duration > (extract(epoch from (time - '2015-08-29 12:36:50'))) )
    THEN extract(epoch from (time - '2015-08-29 12:36:50'))
    ELSE duration
  END AS trim_duration
FROM clamps
WHERE device_id = 27 AND time BETWEEN '2015-08-29 12:36:50' AND '2016-03-15 12:36:50'
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE clamps
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp without time zone,
  duration numeric,
  type character varying(255),
  device_id integer,
  packet_id integer,
  dur_float double precision DEFAULT 0,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT clamps_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Имеется индекс:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_clamps_on_device_id_time
ON clamps
USING btree (device_id, "time");
```

Explaine Analyze:

```
Sort  (cost=149213.28..150770.01 rows=622695 width=21) (actual     time=4263.385..4713.566 rows=1469514 loops=1)
  Sort Key: "time"
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 71816kB
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on clamps  (cost=17535.79..89284.59 rows=622695 width=21) (actual time=190.593..2692.161 rows=1469514 loops=1)
    Recheck Cond: ((device_id = 27) AND ("time" >= '2015-08-29 12:36:50'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2016-03-15 12:36:50'::timestamp without time zone))
    Heap Blocks: exact=17528
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_clamps_on_device_id_time  (cost=0.00..17380.12 rows=622695 width=0) (actual time=186.667..186.667 rows=1469514 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((device_id = 27) AND ("time" >= '2015-08-29 12:36:50'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2016-03-15 12:36:50'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 0.291 ms
Execution time: 5414.691 ms
```

Запрос выполняется секунд 9-13 (хоть explain и показывает 5.5). Можно как-то запрос оптимизировать?

Comment: Может стоит добавить индексы на `time`? `CREATE INDEX idx_bla_bla ON clamps USING BTREE (time);`

Comment: А попробуйте поменять `ORDER BY device_id, time` порядок не изменится т.к. device_id один, а вот фаза сортировки может не понадобится.

Comment: @Mike, не помогло.

Comment: @AndreyM, тоже не повлияло.

Comment: @АлександрАндреев Вы бы для начала определили, какая часть более тяжелая. Уберите ORDER BY. Потом уберите расчетную часть (case). И выполните `select count(1) from (ваш-запрос)`. Сравните время выполнения. И "не помогло" - слишком мало данных, мне интересно было бы планы выполнения сравнить.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ощущение, что потенциальная проблема у вас в условии WHERE с неявным преобразованием типов данных: `time BETWEEN '2015-08-29 12:36:50' AND '2016-03-15 12:36:50'`, попробуйте переписать с CAST и добавить индекс на time (кстати, называть поля базы данных [зарезервированными словами](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) - плохая практика), такая же проблема возможно присутствует и в `extract(epoch from (time - '2015-08-29 12:36:50'))`

Answer (score 1):

Разберем вывод Explaine Analyze

1. Индекс задействуется, причем, индекс очень хорош, ибо задействует все поля выборки и реальное сканирование индекса составляет всего 186.667 ms.

   Тут оптимизировать нечего.
2. Выборка по индексу занимает от 190.593 до 2692.161 ms.

   Можно ли что-то с этим сделать? Если версия базы >= 9.2, то можно построить индекс, который бы задействовал не только поля выборки, но и поля вывода, тогда вся выборка будет делаться исключительно по индексу и к таблице обращения вообще не будет, т.е. этот пункт будет отсутствовать. Если база постарее, то увы, only index scan появился лишь в 9.2.

   Соответсвенно, новый индекс:

   CREATE INDEX index_clamps_on_device_id_time_type_duration
   ON clamps
   USING btree (device_id, "time", type, duration);
3. Сортировка однопроходная, выполняется от 4263.385 до 4713.566 ms.

   Вот он, "добрый" кусок потери времени. К сожалению, единственное, что с этим можно сделать - отказаться от сортировки. Задумайтесь, так ли она нужна?
4. Несостыковка времени выполнения запроса с реально наблюдаемым.

   Напрашивается вопрос, а как производился замер реально наблюдаемого времени выполнения? Не уж-то от момента запуска запроса до появления данных в клиенте? Ну так извините, как на доставку 1.5 млн строк данных до клиента, так и на отображение их непостредственно в клиенте тоже время требуется.

   Время выполнения первого пункта можно сократить лишь уменьшением передаваемых данных (ничего лишнего не тащить) либо увеличением пропускной способности канала между клиентом и сервером.

   Второй - сменой клиента на более шустрый аналог. Если же выборка делается в коде своей программы/скрипта, то сменить подход к получению данных с сервера, не ждать получения всех данных, а забирать небольшими порциями, тогда их в параллельном потоке можно будет уже начать обрабатывать не дожидаясь получения всех данных.

   Еще одна причина несостыковки возможна при обращении к таблице с большим количеством наследованных таблиц. Но думается, не тот случай, при столь подробно составленном вопросе, врядли бы об этом умолчалось, так что эту тему не затрагиваю.

Comment: Спасибо @Vitalts. Сортировка нужна для следующей части запроса – в текущей строке смотрю значение `time` из следующей строки и произвожу некоторые манипуляции.

Comment: @Александр Андреев, Из соседней записи берется лишь time? Попробуйте следующий вариант, сабселектом вытянуть time соседней записи, тогда для любой текущей записи вы будете иметь time соседней и порядок обработки вам уже будет не важен.